# C++ How to treat an array of classes as an array of primary types?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code:

```
class Vector3
{
    public:
        Vector3() : x(values[0]), y(values[1]), z(values[2])
        { x = y = z = 0; }

        float& x;
        float& y;
        float& z;
    private:
        float[3] values;
};

class Model
{
    public:
        Vector3 vertices[64];
};
```

I'm doing this vector class because I want to deal with the values as `X`, `Y`, `Z` in the code, but for some operations I need a contiguous array of values to be passed to a function.
So the whole array of `vertices[64]` need to be `[x0][y0][z0][x1][y1][z1][x2][y2][z2]` etc.

But if I do this:

```
//Get first address:
void* firstAddress = &vertices[0];
//Or
void* firstAddress = vertices;
```

I don't have the contiguous array as I need it (the data is all messed up), and I'm guessing it's because of the pointers I have in the `Vector3` class.
Is there any way I can do get this functionality that I want? (Having a single array of float but dealing with values as x,y,z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,  the Standard doesn't define how references should be implemented, but they'll almost certainly occupy actual memory in your class much a pointer members would, ruining the contiguous data packing you're hoping for....

If your focus is more on the vertices container, and you just want x/y/z member access to elements in it, then you could try something like:

```
template <size_t N>
class Vertices
{
  public:
    class Proxy
    {
      public:
        Proxy(float* p) : x(p[0]), y(p[1]), z(p[2]) { }
        float& x;
        float& y;
        float& z;
    };

    Proxy operator[](size_t n) { return Proxy(&d_[n * 3]); }
    const Proxy operator[](size_t n) const { return Proxy(&d_[n * 3]); }

  private:
    float d_[N * 3];
};
```

Comment: This container fits perfectly, and I wouldn't have to worry if my `Vector3` class is really equal to a `float v[3]`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have member functions instead:

```
class V3
{
    float data[3];

public:
    V3() : data{0,0,0} {}

    float & x() { return data[0]; }
    float & y() { return data[1]; }
    float & z() { return data[2]; }
};
```

You could also omit the constructor and have an aggregate, if that's more suitable.

Comment: How does this help wrt. contiguous array of truplets?

Comment: yeah, "with luck". however, a `static_cast` should suffice to weed out the compilers and/or compiler configurations that don't provide that.

Answer (score 0):

What you have and array of `values` pointers (pointing to arrays of 3 `floats`) with 3 `float` references (`x`, `y`, `z`).  You probably ant something more like:

```
float & x() { return values[0]; }
float & y() { return values[1]; }
float & z() { return values[2]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a guaranteed contiguous array you need to either copy the data into the array, or use compiler-specific guarantees about memory layout, in particular that

- there will be no padding,

and if you want to also access triplets of the array as `Vector3` instances, that

- accessing a `Vector3` at arbitrary address will not cause a trap or inefficiency (we're into *alignment* here).

It so happens that some common libraries such as OpenCV do make such assumptions for their internal image buffers.

But I'm not entirely sure that the code I've seen has not been platform-adapted. So, in practice you have these choices:

- copy the data contiguously to an array (or from it), and/or
- use an existing library that provides this kind of functionality, such as OpenCV.

Note that using member functions instead of references buys you nothing wrt. to the contiguous array problem, but it does make the `Vector3` potentially assignable.

---

**On further reflection**, i was maybe too trigger-happy writing the above. For if you can guarantee total size `3*sizeof(float)`, and that's almost a given (just get rid of those references), then you are guaranteed that you can access a `Vector3` at any address that can hold a `float`, since C++ guarantees arrays with no padding, and since in such an array a `Vector3` can end up at any address that can hold a `float`. So the in-practice problem reduces to making a decision about supporting compilers or compiler configurations that are unable to make `Vector3` of size `3*sizeof(float)`.

I.e.

```
struct Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;
    auto operator[]( int i ) -> float& { return (&x)[i]; }
    auto operator[]( int i ) const -> float const& { return (&x)[i]; }
};

static_assert( sizeof( Vector3 ) == 3*sizeof( float ), "Ungood Vector3 size" );
```

using the fact that members with no intervening access specifier are guaranteed to be in increasing address order.

Disclaimer: off the cuff code, not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: That's a concern I still haven't looked into, so I'm assuming `float v[6] == vector3 v[2]` in memory. If that's not true for all cases (and I'm aiming the code to be multi platform) then I'm stuck with `float v[3]`...

Comment: well i was may too trigger-happy writing this answer. if you can guarantee total size 3*sizeof(float), and that's almost a given, then you are guaranteed that you can access a `Vector3` at any address that can hold a `float`, since C++ guarantees arrays with no padding, and since in such an array a `Vector3` can end up at any address that can hold a `float`. So the in-practice problem reduces to making a decision about supporting compilers or compiler configurations that are unable to make `Vector3` of size 3*sizeof(float).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement for continuous data in the Model, then your Vector is really an alias to a specific triple of data in the model. No float storage required.

```
class Model

    class Vector
        Vector(Model *model_, size_t idx_) : model(model_),idx(idx_) { };
        Model *model;
        size_t idx;
        float & x() { return model->data[3*idx]; }
        float & y() { return model->data[3*idx+1]; }
        float & z() { return model->data[3*idx+2]; }

    float data[64 * 3];
    Vector vectors[64];

    Model() {
        ...
        for( size_t ii = 0; ii < 64; ii++ ) {
            vectors[ii] = new Vector(this,ii);
        }

     Vector & vector(size_t idx) { return vectors[ii]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your Vector3 class a POD you should be able to simply cast your vertices to a float array:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

class Model
{
    public:
        Vector3 vertices[64];
        float* data() {
            return reinterpret_cast<float*>(vertices);
        }
};

int main() {
    Model m;
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        m.vertices[i] = {10+i,100+i,1000+i};
    }
    float *data = m.data();

    for(int i= 0; i < 64*3; ++i) {
        std::cout << data[i] << ", ";
    }
}
```

Only problem could be the Allignment of the structure, but should you use c++11, there is a standard way of alligning the structure, using allignas`alignas(alignof(float[3]))`. I don't know if this is really required.
Also, c++11 gives quite a few options on what to do with Vector3, while still considering it as a POD type.